# What is currently the best way to add a custom dictionary to a neural machine translator that uses the transformer architecture?

Tags: neural-network, nlp, transformer-model, machine-translation, seq2seq

It's common to add a custom dictionary to a machine translator to ensure that terminology from a specific domain is correctly translated. For example, the term server should be translated differently when the document is about data centers, vs when the document is about restaurants.

With a transformer model, this is not very obvious to do, since words are not aligned 1:1. I've seen a couple of papers on this topic, but I'm not sure which would be the best one to use. What are the best practices for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid you cannot easily do that. You cannot easily add new words to the vocabulary because you don't know what embedding it would get during training. You can try to remove some words, or alternatively you can manually change the bias in the final softmax layer to prevent some words from appearing in the translation. Anything else would be pretty difficult to do.

What you want to do is called *domain adaptation*. To get an idea of how domain adaptation is usually done, you can have a look at a [survey paper](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/C18-1111.pdf).

The most commonly used approaches are probably model finetuning or ensembling with a language model. If you want to have parallel data in your domain, you can try to fine-tune your model on that parallel data (with simple SGD, small learning rate).

If you only have monolingual data in the target language, you train a language model on that data. During the decoding, you can mix the probabilities from the domain-specific language and the translation model. Unfortunately, I don't know of any tool that could do this out of the box.

Comment: Thank you, domain adaption is probably the end problem I'm trying to solve, but my goal is to build a machine translator, where the end user can upload a custom dictionary. To do this I would like to get word to word alignment (which is also useful when text is in html and the translation needs to keep the format). I did find one interesting paper here: https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W18-6318.pdf -- what do you think? I guess I'm just trying to decide if this is the right paper to implement, but it seem to have what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yep, the paper looks like it would the job. I would only worry a little what it would do, you add a dictionary of words that weren't in the original training data because the  Transformer would not know how to use them in context.