# Can I customize the dictionary of a pre-trained transformer neural machine translation model?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, pytorch, transformer-model, machine-translation

There are many pre-trained machine translations models available, but it seems like they all need to be run with the dictionary they are trained with. The dictionaries sometimes can have less coverage for my data set (even BPE based ones), and sometimes miss important words as unknowns. What are the best ways to customize the pretrained models to a dictionary learned from my own data set? For example, some way to transfer learn, like unfreezing the encoder layers and retraining?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is currently the best way to add a custom dictionary to a neural machine translator that uses the transformer architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58334235/what-is-currently-the-best-way-to-add-a-custom-dictionary-to-a-neural-machine-tr)

Comment: They are lightly different questions. The other question is asking how can I let an end user upload a custom dictionary. This one is talking about the BPE code dictionary. Pre-trained models use their own dictionary -- say they have a vocabulary of 29345. You have to apply that vocabulary to your text to use the pretrained model, but sometimes it doesn't cover the text well. Is it possible to get your own vocabulary, say through subword-nmt, and then also use the pretrained model -- some sort of transfer learning, like by unfreezing the encoder possibly?